# Only loop through post if ACF field is filled

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, acfpro

I created a custom post type 'Team' which contains all our team members and some information for each person. I added a shortcode that renders a block with our Spotify-list and a picture of someone with headphones. 
The picture is taken from the field 'team_foto_met_koptelefoon', but not everyone has this pictures set. I now want to loop only through the people (posts) that have a picture set in that field and ignore the others so everytime the page is reloaded, the Spotify-block is rendered but every time with a different picture.

I almost got it to work, but sometimes the block disappears, I think because he doesn't show the block if there is no picture set.

```
function dfib_team_spotify_shortcode( $atts ) {
ob_start();
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'team',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'          => 'team_foto_met_koptelefoon',
    'meta_value'        => ' ',
    'meta_compare'      => '!=',
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if( get_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon') ): ?>
        <div class="block__spotify">
            <div class="block__spotify__inner" <?php if( get_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon') ): ?> style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon'); ?>);"<?php endif; ?>>
                <h3 class="block__spotify--title">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
                        <g id="Group_1223" data-name="Group 1223" transform="translate(-1147 -1547.002)">
                            <g id="Group_1159" data-name="Group 1159" transform="translate(1147 1547.002)">
                                <path id="Path_779" data-name="Path 779" d="M59.555,188.083a30,30,0,1,0,30,30A30,30,0,0,0,59.555,188.083Zm13.758,43.27a1.869,1.869,0,0,1-2.571.622C63.7,227.67,54.83,226.7,44.388,229.083a1.869,1.869,0,0,1-.833-3.645c11.428-2.613,21.23-1.489,29.138,3.344A1.87,1.87,0,0,1,73.313,231.353Zm3.671-8.169a2.34,2.34,0,0,1-3.217.77c-8.062-4.956-20.356-6.391-29.894-3.5a2.338,2.338,0,1,1-1.36-4.475c10.9-3.306,24.441-1.705,33.7,3.986A2.339,2.339,0,0,1,76.984,223.184Zm.317-8.506c-9.67-5.743-25.621-6.271-34.853-3.469a2.806,2.806,0,1,1-1.629-5.37c10.6-3.217,28.213-2.6,39.346,4.013a2.806,2.806,0,0,1-2.864,4.826Z" transform="translate(-29.555 -188.083)" fill="#fff"/>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    <a href="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6AZ1LZ8PKbkXkoBopPWDqM" target="blank">luister</a> naar</br> onze favoriete songs
                </h3>
                <div class="spotify--player">
                    <h2>#favoritetunes</h2>
                    <p>geniet van onze karaktervolle muzieklijst</p>
                    <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/6AZ1LZ8PKbkXkoBopPWDqM" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="spotify--img">
                    <?php if( get_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon') ): ?>
                        <img src="<?php the_field('team_foto_met_koptelefoon'); ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php 
$myvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $myvariable;
}
?>

<?php }
```

Comment: hey this field set as black if they haven't any value ?

Comment: Why are you comparing the meta key to a space in your query? Please don’t say you are using _that_ to mean “empty”.

Comment: below I have share my answer please let me know if you have any concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'team',                     
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'   => 'ID',
        'order'     =>  'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,        
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'team_foto_met_koptelefoon',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )                      
        ),
    );

$team_foto_met_koptelefoon = get_posts($args);
_e("<pre>");
print_r($team_foto_met_koptelefoon); //Your posts
_e("</pre>");
```